# Retag request: [search-engine] & [search-engines]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There are (as of now) 18 questions tagged as [search-engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine)

21 questions tagged as [search-engines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engines)

Here's requesting merging of the above 2 tags. Optionally, [search-engines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engines) could be made as a synonym of [search-engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merge is complete and [search-engines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engines) has been remapped to [search-engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine)